# Is there any hope to save this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $x, y\ge 0$ be reals and $n\ge 1$ be a natural number such that $x^n<y$. Then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x+\varepsilon)^n<y$.

My attempt is this:

Let $x, y\ge0$ be reals and $n\ge1$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists a real $K>0$ such that
$$(x+\varepsilon)^n < x^n + K\varepsilon$$
as is easily shown by induction. Now,
$$x^n + K\varepsilon < y\impliedby \varepsilon < \frac{y-x^n}{K}$$
and since $x^n<y$, there does exist an $\tilde\varepsilon$ such that $0<\tilde\varepsilon<\frac{y-x^n}{K}$.

**Issue with this proof:** It is **not** ensured that the same $K$ will also work with such an $\tilde\varepsilon$, hence rendering the proof incomplete.

---

**Question:** Is there any way to "fix" this proof, preserving the original ideas? If not, can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: It is enough to prove that the map $x \mapsto x^n$ is continuous. This can be done by proving that the map $x \mapsto x$ is continuous and then proving that the product of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Is there any hope to save this proof?" tells nothing about the subject of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea, one can handle the case $x=0$ and $x>0$ separately.

**Case 1**. If $x=0$ and $0<y,$ take $\epsilon=\min(1/2,y)>0.$ Then one has $$\epsilon^n<y.$$

**Case 2**. If $x>0$ and $x^n<y$, take $$\epsilon=\min\left(\frac x 2,\frac{y-x^n}K\right)>0,\qquad (1)$$ where $$K=(2^n-1)x^{n-1}>0.$$ One proceeds to show that $$(x+\epsilon)^n<y.$$ By (1), $\epsilon<x$, hence one has by the binomial coefficients that $$(x+\epsilon)^n=x^n+\epsilon(nx^{n-1}+\cdots+\epsilon^{n-1})$$
$$<x^n+\epsilon(2^n-1)x^{n-1}=x^n+K\epsilon$$
$$\leq x^n+K\cdot \frac{y-x^n}K=y,$$ where the last inequality follows from (1). QED

Comment: That was genius! Thanks!

Comment: QC_QAOA's answer was also spot-on. But I ended up picking this so that the people will also notice this as "the accepted answer" and QC_QAOA's highest voted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is actually fine. For a fixed $x,y,$ and $n$ (note here that the question is asking about fixed values and not, for example, all $n=1,2,...$) simply choose

$$\epsilon=\frac{y-x^n}{2K}$$

where $K$ is determined by some function of the $x,y,$ and $n$. If you want it explicitly written out, we have

$$(x+\epsilon)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\epsilon^{j}x^{n-j}=x^n+\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}\epsilon^{j}x^{n-j}=x^n+\epsilon\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}\epsilon^{j-1}x^{n-j}$$

Now, to bound this sum we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}\epsilon^{j-1}x^{n-j}<\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n$$

which is true for $0<\epsilon<1$ (this is analogous to your $K$ term but here it depends on $x,y,$ and $n$).

---

EDIT: To really drive home how $K$ is only a function of $x,y,$ and $n$. I will restate what we have shown while explicitly connecting it to $K$.

For $0<\epsilon<1$ we have

$$(x+\epsilon)^n<x^n+K\epsilon$$

where $K$ is given by

$$K=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n$$

(in fact, this $K$ does not even depend on $y$). Again, note that this does not depend on $\epsilon$.

---

Using this, simply choose

$$\epsilon=\frac{y-x^n}{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n}$$

Putting it all together

$$(x+\epsilon)^n=x^n+\epsilon\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j}\epsilon^{j-1}x^{n-j}<x^n+\epsilon\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n$$

$$=x^n+\frac{y-x^n}{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n-1\right)x^n=x^n+y-x^n=y$$

Comment: You write that $K$ is determined by some function of $x, y, n$, which is *not* the case (it also depends on $\varepsilon$), for if it didn't depend on $\varepsilon$, then the relation $(x+\varepsilon)^n<x^n+K\varepsilon$ would hold for all $\varepsilon>0$, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Atom See the edit. You can in fact bound $K$ in terms of $x,y,$ and $n$ without involving $\epsilon$ (at least for $\epsilon<1$ which is the region we are actually interested in). The difficulty you might be having is that your $K$ DOES depend on $\epsilon$, would you mind editing your post and explicitly writing your $K$ (or if you don't have an explicit formula then writing out your induction proof)

Comment: Ah, now I see it! I just saw the first line of your proof and ignorantly wrote my comment. Sorry for that. However, I don't get how you get $K =  \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^n  - 1 \right)^n$. Can you explain? (I however understand why $K = (1+x)^n - x^n$ can also work.)

Comment: Whoops, looks like I forgot an $x^n$ (missed an $x$ character and then copied the error forward) when I typed this up. Basically, I just went https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28binom%28n%2Ck%29x%5E%28n-k%29%2C%28k%2C1%2Cn%29%29

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original idea is that you'd like to preserve, but here's a very simple approach:

Since $x^n<y$ and taking $n$-th roots is monotonic on non-negative reals, we also have $x < y^{1/n}$. Hence, we can define
$$
\Delta := y^{1/n} - x > 0.
$$
You want to show there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x+\varepsilon)^n < y$, which by the same reasoning is equivalent to $x+\varepsilon < y^{1/n}$. Using $\Delta$ this condition translates to $\varepsilon < \Delta$. Hence, any $0<\varepsilon<\Delta$ will do, for example $\varepsilon=\Delta/2$.

Comment: I have not yet developed $n$-th roots, so can't use it.